# NETGEAR wireless usb N150 adapter on ASUS x401a using 14.04 version

Tags: netgear

The N150 adapter works and I get good solid connection. The problem is that I need to reboot several times before the driver gets recognized. There are a couple of scenarios that happen.

1. On booting up the wireless connection is not highlighted. That is the "Enable WiFi" cannot be turned on or it's not even there using the upper right hand icon for network connection.
2. On booting up the WiFi is enabled however the internal wireless is recognized of the computer (Ralink RT5390) and the NETGEAR adapter is not recognized.
   or
3. On booting up the WiFi is enabled and both the internal wireless and the dongle is recognized and I choose the dongle and get the connection.

So I think the internal wireless needs to be disabled I believe and also I need to somehow to get the 'WiFi Enabled' on boot up with the dongle being activated.

Comment: I'd save outputs of `dmesg` and `lsmod` for every scenario, and check differences with something, e.g. with `vimdiff` *(don't blame me for mention of vim, it's just the best diff utility I know; plain `diff` is awful)*. Add the files to the question would help too.

Comment: I did the reinstall network manager execution - still the same issues.

Comment: I installed vim but can't get files nor the differences to view

Comment: `dmesg` and `lsmod` are commands. To get their output to a file, redirect them, for example: `dmesg > dmesg-wifi-works-dongle-recognized`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of `network-manager`.
You can re-install network manager and it would the reset it.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager`

Comment: I did reinstall network-manager but same issues